# BindingHandler that add Virtual Binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

```
     <div style="display: inline-block" data-bind="autocomplete : { multi:true, values:values}">
     </div>
```

I have a autocomplete bindingHandler. Now I want to add some extra code if its a multi select. The code below I get to work but I want the bindingHandler to add it.

```
 <div class='auto'>    
    <!-- ko foreach : values -->          
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->     
    <span>       
     <div style="display: inline-block" data-bind="autocomplete : { multi:true, values: values}">
     </div>
    </span>    
</div>
```

I tried to do something like this in the Init of the autocomplete bindingHandler. But I guess that the binding doesn't becomes added correctly. Is it possible to add virutal binding like this in init on a bininghandler?

```
 $element.wrap("<div class='auto'>");
 $element.wrap("<span>");
 $element.parent().before("<!-- ko foreach : values --><span data-bind='text: $data'></span><!-- /ko -->");
```

if I do it like this with no virtual binding it works.

```
$element.wrap("<div class='auto'>");
        $element.wrap("<span>");
        $element.parent().before("<div><span data-bind='text: $data'></span></div>");

        var $div = $element.parent().prev();

        ko.applyBindingsToNode($div[0], function () {
            return {
                foreach: value.values
            };
        });
```

But I cant surround it with a div becuse the design will not be right. Is it possible to add virtual binding?

Comment: Adding strings of HTML to the page goes against the purpose of Knockout.  Instead, you could use a `template` binding.

Comment: I'am so with you with the purpose of Knockout. Maybe I have to rethink the first binding. But how do you handle templates with bindingHandlers. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on setting the HTML in JavaScript (but please don't), you can use an internal function that binds things.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.thing = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var html = "The thing is <!-- ko text: thing -->"
                   + "<!-- /ko -->"
        ko.utils.setHtml(element, html);
    }
}
```

This has potential security problems (that I don't know anything about), but seem to be remidied by returning `{ 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };` from the init handler of your binding handler.

### [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sxdsF/)

Comment: Does ko.utils.setHtml() apply binding on the new html or it just change the inner html of the element ??

Comment: It does both.  It changes the HTML, and then applies bindings to it.